# Change Default Database Connection in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas

Our team are working with Excel that gets data from other sources -- MS SQL server or OLAP cube. When we connect to a server, it shows a default database.

[image]

Is there a way that we can change this default database to the other one?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I would assume that Excel displays the databases in alphabetical order, and just uses the first as default.

Comment: Hi all,

Did someone know how to do this now?
As I can see Excel do not set the first database as default because somehow I have third database in the list as a default and I need set another one (request form the customer).
I tried to change Database name, model name, database ID but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Data Sources

Find the data source you're using and "Configure" it. On the third screen of the wizard you can change the default database.